# Stack gradients in -webkit-gradient

Tags: css, webkit, gradient, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

Can I combine 3 gradients into one -webkit-gradient? I want to have an image that has a radial gradient for the "background" and "middle-ground" and a linear gradient for the "foreground". Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Use three overlapping elements (`divs` are as good as any other), one each for the back-, mid-, and foregrounds. Style each one with its own gradient, using `transparent` as the underlying color, and the others will show through.

---

*Edit:* here's a two-layer version that should help get you started: http://jsbin.com/awali       (requires a Webkit browser)

Comment: The link is bad. The page displays, "document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "This URL does not have any code saved to it.";"

Comment: @Atlas: you're right! Sorry about the broken link, I must have mis-copied it. It's fixed now, though.